# <a href> tag to open excel file

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-controls

I am currently using Visual Studio 2010 and wanted to have a link on my page that opened in a new window a simple excel sheet that is on a local drive.

I have used a simple  tag to open this file.

```
  <a href="S:/BettyTest.xlsx" target="_blank" title="Excel Test">Excel Book Test</a>
```

This opens the file as requested but it doesn't open this to a new window.  I am currently using IE8.  When clicking the link, I get the prompt to either open or save the workbook and when I select open, this opens over the web page.

Comment: I think this will be dependant on client preferences - which of course you cannot change ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your href needs to be different

Something like this

file:///S:/BettyTest.xlsx

Comment: Not Working in my case

Answer (score 2):

you can use Google Document Viewer to view all files

Here is the Url to view

```
http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_FILE_URL
```

I am not sure about how its working but it will open your file instead of download

Thanks

Comment: Many thanks for this i will take a look at using the google document viewer.